# TextView.setText(int) causes app to crash

Tags: java, android, textview

I was implementing the following Java code in Android Studio:

```
private void display(int number) {
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
    quantityTextView.setText(number);
    ...
}
```

This is a part of a larger application.

As you can see, I've passed only an integer value to the `quantityTextView.setText(number)` method.

When running the app, it crashes as soon as this method is called. Can you tell me why such a thing is happening?

Comment: Please paste the stack trace (error text).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, use `String.valueOf()`, like this:

```
private void display(int number) {
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
    quantityTextView.setText(String.valueOf(number));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `setText()` accepts only String values or Resource ID of a `String` (which is infact int).

Check here: [setText() Method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int))

You can use `String.valueOf(number);`  as input parameter of `setText()` or you can refer to String ID in XML with `getResources().getString(R.string.number)` as input value.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the integer to string before putting it in the TextView:

```
quantityTextView.setText(Integer.toString(number));
```

or simply

```
quantityTextView.setText(number+"");
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code is crashing is that [`setText(int)` expects a resource ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)). It's not very well documented, so you'd be forgiven for thinking that you could pass it an integer and have the `TextView` convert it to text.

You should first convert it to a String, for example with:

```
String.valueOf(number)
```

and then it will be alright.

Answer (score 0):

setText() method of TextView accepts CharSequence, not integers. So, you must convert your number to String before.

Try to use this:

```
quantityTextView.setText(Integer.toString(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that, setText() only expects string or char[].

So either you can perform type casting or you can add quotes with the number

(1). by type casting 
String.valueOf(number)

(2). by adding "" with the number
quantityTextView.setText(""+number);
or
quantityTextView.setText(number+"");